# Wordpress "Notice: Undefined offset: 1"

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I've found a code snippet to display the categories in a dropdown menu. It works fine but when I turn on the `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`, Wordpress shows the above mentioned warning. I've just started with php and cannot figure out how to fix this warning. Could anyone help me out on this one and tell me why am I getting this message?

```
<?php
function replace_id_for_slug($option){
        $categories = get_categories("hide_empty=0");
        preg_match('/value="(\d*)"/', $option[0], $matches);
        $id = $matches[1]; //problem on this line!
        $slug = "";
    foreach($categories as $category){
        if($category->cat_ID == $id){
            $slug = $category->slug;
            }
    }
return preg_replace("/value=\"(\d*)\"/", "value=\"$slug\"", $option[0]);
}
$select = wp_dropdown_categories("show_option_none=Category&hierarchical=1&hide_empty=0&echo=0");
$select = preg_replace_callback("#<option[^>]*>[^<]*</option>#", "replace_id_for_slug", $select);
echo $select; ?>
```

Comment: What's the warning you are having?

Comment: "Notice: Undefined offset: 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('/value="(\d*)"/', $option[0], $matches);
$id = $matches[1]; //problem on this line!
```

You didn't check whether anything was matched. If there was no match, then `$matches[1]` does not exist. Fairly self-explanatory!

I'd suggest something like:

```
function replace_id_for_slug($option) {

    $categories = get_categories("hide_empty=0");
    preg_match('/value="(\d*)"/', $option[0], $matches);

    if (!$matches) {
       // return as if $id is empty if no match
       return preg_replace('/value="(\d*)"/', 'value=""', $option[0]);
    }

    $id   = $matches[1];
    $slug = "";

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category->cat_ID == $id) {
            $slug = $category->slug;
        }
    }

    return preg_replace('/value="(\d*)"/', 'value="' . $slug . '"', $option[0]);
}
```

---

#### If this is a Wordpress core function:

What's really happening is that the Wordpress authors are *really* lazy, and instead of writing the above fix, they allowed PHP to just ignore this issue with a `E_NOTICE`. You are seeing it because their "debug mode" is turning on certain error-reporting features.

Comment: `replace_id_for_slug` does not look like a wordpress core function to me.

Comment: @hakre: Oh well, if it's not, then he can just apply the fix!

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because the regexp doesn't match anything, and thus $matches[1] is undefined.

If `preg_match` doesn't find anything, then $matches is an empty array. You can change the code to check if `preg_match` actually matched something:

```
if (preg_match('/value="(\d*)"/', $option[0], $matches)){
    $id = $matches[1];
} else {
    // set id to a different value.
}
```

Comment: This is the whole message I see on the page when it loads:'Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\v3\posts-page.php on line 57
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0002 672232 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0
2 0.0003 677064 require( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-blog-header.php' ) ..\index.php:17
3 1.1805 26641288 require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-includes\template-loader.php' ) ..\wp-blog-header.php:16
4 1.1817 26692000 include( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\v3\posts-page.php' ) ..\template-loader.php:43
5 1.2072 26848120 preg_replace_callback ( ) ..\posts-page.php:67
6 '

Comment: Line 57 is "$id = $matches[1]; //problem on this line!"

Comment: @Juhana: It's not a full solution, and there is probably no "different value" to give to `$id`.